# I want to combine two sql queries resukt

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want to combine both queries result and final result showing of both queries

I tried with union but it was not work

```
Select Distinct PersonNameWorked, COUNT(ProcessInstanceAppianId)as Num_Of_Jobs,  sum(ExpectedTaskEffort) as Workunits,
cast((cast((sum(TaskInstanceEffort) / 60.00) as Decimal(5,2)))/count (Distinct  cast(TaskInstanceCompleted as date) ) as Decimal(5,2)) as WorkingHours,
ROUND((1.00- sum(CAST(TaskInstanceEffort AS FLOAT))/sum(CAST(ExpectedTaskEffort AS FLOAT)))*100,2) as EfforVariance
from pathfinder..PFTask

where TaskInstanceCompleted  between '2019-9-03 00:30:00' and '2019-9-04 00:30:00'
  and KeyProcessStream in (26769,26768,28788,26760,26761,26755,29529)
and KeyPerson in (1347718,1332622,619682)
--and ProcessInstanceAppianId='-2136985491'
--and TaskInstanceCompleted
group by PersonNameWorked, KEYPERSON
order by PersonNameWorked asc
union all
select PersonNameWorked, cast(sum(PFTaskInstanceRating)*1.00/count(distinct ProcessInstanceAppianId) as decimal (5,2))as Rating
from pathfinder..PFTask
where TaskInstanceCompleted  between '2019-9-03 00:30:00' and '2019-9-04 00:30:00'
and KeyPerson in (1347718,1332622,619682)
and PFTaskInstanceRating is not null
group by PersonNameWorked, KEYPERSON
order by PersonNameWorked asc
```

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: There can  be only 1 order by clause in the query having union all. Remove first order by clause.

Comment: You rarely never need to combine GROUP BY with SELECT DISTINCT.

Comment: the tag for SQL Server is `sql-server`, and there also exist version tags. Please use `sql-server` tag plus a version tag like `sql-server-2017` in ALL your future questions. `mysql` tag is for a competing product by oracle corporation with  different syntax

Comment: The above query worked, but result is not as expected, so basically my question was that I want result of both query but final result contains, PersonNameWorked,Num_Of_Jobs,Workunits,WorkingHours,EfforVariance and Rating @fa06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `union all/union` you need to have the same number of column in both queries which are missing in your case - so it throws error

```
Select Distinct PersonNameWorked, COUNT(ProcessInstanceAppianId)as Num_Of_Jobs,  sum(ExpectedTaskEffort) as Workunits,
cast((cast((sum(TaskInstanceEffort) / 60.00) as Decimal(5,2)))/count (Distinct  cast(TaskInstanceCompleted as date) ) as Decimal(5,2)) as WorkingHours,
ROUND((1.00- sum(CAST(TaskInstanceEffort AS FLOAT))/sum(CAST(ExpectedTaskEffort AS FLOAT)))*100,2) as EfforVariance
from pathfinder..PFTask
where TaskInstanceCompleted  between '2019-9-03 00:30:00' and '2019-9-04 00:30:00'
  and KeyProcessStream in (26769,26768,28788,26760,26761,26755,29529)
and KeyPerson in (1347718,1332622,619682)
--and ProcessInstanceAppianId='-2136985491'
--and TaskInstanceCompleted
group by PersonNameWorked, KEYPERSON

union all

select PersonNameWorked, null,null,null,cast(sum(PFTaskInstanceRating)*1.00/count(distinct ProcessInstanceAppianId) as decimal (5,2))as Rating
from pathfinder..PFTask
where TaskInstanceCompleted  between '2019-9-03 00:30:00' and '2019-9-04 00:30:00'
and KeyPerson in (1347718,1332622,619682)
and PFTaskInstanceRating is not null
group by PersonNameWorked, KEYPERSON
```

Comment: You have removed the `ORDER BY` you might want to mention why

Comment: Indeed, the error message is caused by the attempt to ORDER BY then union, rather than the number of columns differing. That would have been a different error message

Comment: @RiggsFolly, order by in union does not work in the way sometimes we think

Comment: @CaiusJard, order by will not cause any error  - you can give a try

Comment: @fa06 I know that, I was just suggesting after UVing that you might like to tell the OP why you have removed it :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Sorry, I couldn't understand that :)

Comment: @fa06 faithfully promise it does; take a look at the screenshot I just added to my answer. Of course, it doesn't help that the OP tagged `mysql` and is using `sqlserver`, and mysql probably accepts all sorts of ****ty behavior like this.. But the OP is certainly using sqls; that's not a mysql error message

Answer (score 0):

In supplement to fa06s answer, because he makes a really good point that your column counts need to be equal between the two queries, this error is caused by your attempt to ORDER BY each query, then do the union:

[image]

You must not ORDER BY each query before you UNION. You do the ORDER BY once, at the end, after all the unions.

Right:

```
SELECT.. 
FROM ... 
UNION 
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
ORDER BY ... <-- just order by once. It works on the whole union output
```

Wrong:

```
SELECT.. 
FROM ...
ORDER BY ... <-- don't do it here as well
UNION 
SELECT ... 
FROM ... 
ORDER BY ...
```

ORDER BY is processed last by SQL, after unions have been done. ORDER BY uses the column names defined by the first query in the union:

```
SELECT a FROM table1
UNION 
SELECT b FROM table2
UNION 
SELECT c FROM table3
ORDER BY a            <--the column is named after whatever the first query called it
```

If it helps, think of it as happening like this, internally:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT a 
  UNION 
  SELECT b 
  UNION 
  SELECT c  
) x
ORDER BY x.a
```

Once you remove the ORDER BY, you'll then be faced with an error about your column counts:

[image]

Queries that are unioned must have the same count of columns because the resultesets are stuck together vertically: 5 columns on query 1 must me matched to 5 columns on query 2, so that the 50 rows from query 1 and 100 rows from query 2 can become a single result set 150 rows long.

If you don't have any values for some columns in query 2 etc, make them null:

```
  SELECT 1 as a, 2 as b
  UNION 
  SELECT 2, null         <-- there are no values for column b for this query,
                             so just use a constant value like 0, 1, null..
                             whatever is appropriate
  ORDER BY a
```

Note also that because the first query in a union defines the column names, the only point in aliasing the columns in the second query is to make the code more self documenting. It has no functional purpose